# Javascript sort

Tags: javascript

Not sure what I am doing wrong.  I am trying to sort the results.

```
function makeSidebar() {
    var html = "";
    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (!gmarkers[i].isHidden()) {
        html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + gmarkers[i].myteam + '<\/a><br>';
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = html;
}
```

I have tried html.sort(); and a few different ideas.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to sort on? `myteam` value or just the HTML strings?

Comment: What you are trying to sort? i dont see relevant code

Comment: <a href="javascript:myclick()"> is bad form, use <a href="javascript://" onclick="myclick(' + i + ')">

Comment: I am trying to sort the html results.

Answer (score 0):

`html` in your code is a string and strings don't have a sort function. Arrays however do, so you should sort the teams first, then display them:

```
function compare(a, b) {
    if (a.myteam < b.myteam) return -1;
    if (a.myteam > b.myteam) return 1;
    return 0;
} 

gmarkers.sort(compare);

function makeSidebar() {
        var html = "";
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
          if (!gmarkers[i].isHidden()) {
            html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + gmarkers[i].myteam + '<\/a><br>';
          }
        }
        document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = html;
      }
```

Comment: Interesting, tried the code and still the same result.  Does a.myteam or b.myteam have to specified?

TIL I am a major javascript newbie...

Comment: I guess they are specified since  you use `gmarkers[i].myteam` in your code? Could you post the full structure of gmarkers?

Comment: `// A function to create the marker and set up the event window
      function createMarker(point,team,html,category) {
        var marker = new GMarker(point,gicons[category]);
        // === Store the category and name info as a marker properties ===
        marker.mycategory = category;                                 
        marker.myteam = team;
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
        });
        gmarkers.push(marker);
        return marker;
      }`

Comment: According to Google Maps' doc, GMarker doesn't have a myteam property. What are you trying to display exactly, which information? If you just want to display the markers' titles, you can use `getTitle()` (replace `myteam` everywhere in your code by `getTitle()`).